# SQL Query suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have wrote this query. it gives me an error, it has something to do with escaping quotes. if someone can help me with that, that be great.

Thing Im trying to do:

**If website column has data then show company_name as link, if website column has no data, display company name normally**

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN qpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' THEN '<a href="http://',wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`,'" target="_blank">'
    ,wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name`,
    CASE WHEN qpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' THEN '</a>') AS Company_Name, 
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Input_Product_Name`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Brand_Name`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Category`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Annotation`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Standard`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`City`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Province`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Phone`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Email`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`
FROM wpiy_test_data_2
```

Error It gives me:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN qpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' THEN '<a href="http://',wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`,'" target="_blank">'
    ,wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name`,
    CASE WHEN qpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' THEN '</a>') AS Company_Name, 
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Input_Product_Name`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Brand_Name`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Category`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Annotation`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Standard`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`City`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Province`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Phone`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Email`,
       wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`
FROM wpiy_test_data_2 LIMIT 0, 25
**MySQL said: Documentation**

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`,'" target="_blank">'
    ,wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_' at line 2
```

Comment: Just look at the formatting of your very question above.  You can see some issues with what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Final Query that worked for me.

```
SELECT 
( CASE 
WHEN wpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' THEN CONCAT('<a href="http://',wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`,'" target="_blank">' ,wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name`,'</a>') 
ELSE wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name` end) AS Company_Name,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name` AS Actual_Name,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Input_Product_Name`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Brand_Name`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Category`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Usage_Annotation`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Standard`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`City`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Province`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Phone`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Email`,
wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`
FROM 
wpiy_test_data_2
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings you need to use the `CONCAT()` function.

You need an `ELSE` clause to display something else when the condition is not true.

You also need an `END` keyword at the end of a `CASE` expression.

```
    CASE WHEN qpiy_test_data_2.`Website` != '' 
    THEN CONCAT('<a href="http://',wpiy_test_data_2.`Website`,'" target="_blank">'
                ,wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name`,'</a>') 
    ELSE wpiy_test_data_2.`Company_Name`
    END AS Company_Name,
```